# Uncaught ReferenceError: Dygraph is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dygraphs

I am using express.js, through my application i am rendering dygraph chart on client side. 
[This is what my index.jade file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr39c.png)

whenever i am going on my browser the console shows this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: Dygraph is not defined

I have a another html file with same contents and it is working fine for me with no error. .[I have attached the screenshot of both files here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UuJc.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've done an error typing 'text/javascript'. Your code says 'text/javscript' :) Seems like just a typo mistake.

Comment: thanks @philippsh, sorry for the inconvenience stackoverflow community.
From next time i will be more vigilant.